# How to remove or replace the key value from .env using bash script

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to remove the value or replace the value in .env file using bash script

in my .env file I have

```
TEST_VAR=testVariable
```

I have inserted this TEST_VAR using bash script using the below script

```
#!/bin/bash
echo TEST_VAR="testVariable" >> .env
```

The problem is if I run the bash script again it will enter TEST_VAR multiple times in .env. How can I replace the value or may be remove this key pair value.

for example

If I run again the bash script with changed value

```
#!/bin/bash
echo TEST_VAR="updateValue" >> .env
```

it should show in .env file

TEST_VAR=updatedValue

rather than below

TEST_VAR=testVariable
TEST_VAR=updatedValue

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this, assuming the .env you want to update is `file.env`:

```
sed -i~ '/^TEST_VAR=/s/=.*/="UpdateValue"/' file.env
```

Explanation: the command `sed -i~` is able to edit a file in place; i.e. without the need to make a copy. The old version of the file will go to `file.env~`.

The command `s/=.*/="UpdateValue"/` changes everything after the `=` to `="UpdateValue"`. The command applies only to lines beginning with `TEST_VAR=` which is expressed by prepending the regex `/^TEST_VAR=/` to the `sed` command above.

Comment: Hi. I have tried but is giving an error sed: 1: "file.env": invalid command code f

Comment: I thing you made a tipo. This command is working. What is the full name of your .env file?

Comment: The name of the file is .env.test

Comment: In that case, you have to issue `sed -i '/^TEST_VAR=/s/=.*/="UpdateValue"/' .env.test`.

Comment: I tried it with this but it gives sed: 1: ".env.test": invalid command code .

Comment: How did you issue the command? By copying and pasting, or by entering manually each character on the keyboard?

Comment: I copied the above command and paste it in my shell script. The only thing I change is the file name and then run this sh file using terminal.

Comment: If you are on BSD or a Mac, you need `-i ''` instead of just `-i`.

Comment: @tripleee: Thank you for pointing that out, I will edit my answer. However, `-i ''` with a separating space doesn't work in my environment, but `-i''` without space does.

Comment: @tripleee yes I am on MAC

Comment: @PierreFrançois That is syntactically identical to just `-i`. What you can do is to explicitly pass an argument, like `-i~`; this creates a backup file, but is reasonably portable between Linux and *BSD. and is arguably a good safeguard at least until you can verify that the command does work correctly. Or else just leave off the `-i` option and explain how to add it back on different platforms depending on requirements.

Comment: @PierreFrançois. I have one more problem I am getting bad flag in substitute command: '/'  and sometimes bad flag in substitute command: 't'. Looks like the string has some special characters. Do you know what could be the problem. If you want I can create a question for this.

Comment: Yes, since this seems to be be a new problem, I suggest you to post a new question. If I answer you here, which is not the right place and under an incorrect title, nobody will be able to contribute.